# In what conditions should I prefer io.h to windows.h?

Tags: c++, windows, system

I am working on a project related to Systems Programming on Windows. For that I was pointed toward `windows.h`. Now I have come across `io.h`. What exactly is the difference between them?

For example, since I am porting an application that has already been deployed on Linux, the file open function is `open` while on Windows, if I use `windows.h`, the file open function will be [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and if I use `io.h`, it will be [_open()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`io.h` originally provided access to declarations for the low-level I/O primitives in Unix and associated constants and such. Since quite a bit of code depended on it, many (most?) compilers for other systems provided a header by the same name, and some library functions that worked (at least mostly) like the ones in Unix.

Windows.h is (sort of) a rough analog for Windows--a header that gives access to (declarations for) the functions, constants, etc. for Windows. The big difference is that Windows.h does a lot more than the basic, low-level I/O covered by `io.h`, instead covering all the GUI functions, etc.

So: if you want to write code that does I/O at a fairly low level on Unix-like systems and can also port to other systems like Windows, you probably want to use `io.h`. If you want to do system programming specifically for Windows, you almost certainly want to use `windows.h`.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, all of these various I/O functions on Windows map to calls into the Win32 API (e.g., `CreateFile` for your specific question). So, if you want to use this API directly, prefer windows.h . If you want to use various (compatibility) wrappers, whether standard C++ lib, standard IO lib, the POSIX subsystem, etc..., then you can use other include files.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to write portable code, you would use `stdio.h`.

Windows.h includes all the headers you need to create a Windows application (all of the basic Win32 API headers and preprocessor directives).  If you are just looking to read/write files, and wish to do so in a portable fashion, that is not the header file you would choose.

Comment: The question is tagged C++. You *can* use `<stdio.h>` (or `<cstdio>`), but it's usually better to use the C++ library.